# Create list of image with scrollable bar for tkinter

Tags: tkinter

I know how to create images and also a scrollable listbox, but when I combined the two elements it does not work. Any ideas to implement it?

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        text = tk.Text(self, wrap="none")
        vsb = tk.Scrollbar(orient="vertical", command=text.yview)
        text.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
        vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        text.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        for i in range(20):
            # b = tk.Button(self, text="Button #%s" % i)
            photo = tk.PhotoImage(file='img.png')
            photo = photo.subsample(2)

            b = tk.Label(self,image=photo)
            # b.pack(side='bottom',fill='x')
            text.window_create("end", window=b)
            text.insert("end", "\n")

        text.configure(state="disabled")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

It can view list of images if

```
b = tk.Label(self,image=photo)
```

becomes this

```
b = tk.Label(self,text='test')
```

Comment: show the code you have.

Comment: I don't know why you got so many negatives. This was a good question and helped me a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Every image object must keep a reference.
The problem can be solve by adding

```
b = tk.Label(self,image=photo)
b.image = photo # keep a reference
```

Details can be refer [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm).